# Handlebars with Backbone iterating trouble

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I have a problem with a "each" loop in a handlebars template:

I pass to the handlebars template one object as follows:

```
var data = {
   blog = blogModel, // Backbone Model
   user = userModel  // Backbone Model
}

this.el.html(template(data.toJSON()))
```

This is my models structure:

**blogModel**

```
  title: "myblog", 
  posts: [{
        text: "first post",
        datetime: "12/10/2010
      },
      {
        text: "second post",
        datetime: "10/10/2010
      }
        ...
  ]
```

**userModel**

```
  name: "John",
  email: "john@gmail.com"
```

**Handlebars template**

```
{{#each blog.posts}}
   <div>{{title}}</div>
    ...
   <span>{{user.email}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

My problem is that I can´t output {{user.email}} because it´s in the context of {{#each blog.posts}}, it seems that only can output the blog properties.

If I put the {{user.email}} out of the loop it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can step up one level in the scope using `../` so something like this should work:

```
{{#each blog.posts}}
    ...
   <span>{{../user.email}}</span>
{{/each}}
```